# Finding Distinct values across multiple columns and rows in SQL

Tags: sql, db2

I have data like this

```
Id   code1 code2 code3 code4 code5 code6
1      2     3    4     5     6     7
1      4     5    2     3     7     6
1      7     6    5     2     3     4   
1      5     7    6     4     3     2
1      7     5    6     3     2     4
```

I need to identify the distinct codes from this set of 6 codes across 5 rows and 6 columns and display them in any order of 6 rows with ID and code

OUTPUT

```
ID  Code
1   7
1   6
1   2
1   3
1   5
1   4
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9mbn.png)

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: UNION each column.

Comment: Am using DB2 for this

Answer (score 0):

One method is to use `union` :

```
select id, code
from (select id, code1 as code
      from table t
      union
      select id, code2
      from table t
       . . . 
     select id, code6
     from table t
    ) t;
```

Comment: The outer distinct is utterly redundant.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. How do i compare with the target data where they have Id and codes stored in same format but in different order. I need to make sure that same codes are present in target even though the order is different

Comment: @SabarishBapu: rows in a table have no order

Comment: the output mentioned in the question is present in target but the codes are in different order. I wanna make sure that the same set of codes are present between the output i got and the data stored in target table

Comment: @SabarishBapu Did I get you right that you need 2 things: 1) Get all distinct codes from all 6 columns (which has been already done) and 2) Compare the result with contents of some another table `T(ID, Code)` to check if your distinct codes are exactly the same as in table `T` for given `ID`?